# React key={row._id} not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to read the mongodb default _id property in a react jsx block. However I am unable to read it. I have confirmed the _id key exist on the row object passed to the functional component ProductTableSingleRow

```
const ProductTableSingleRow = ({ row, index }) => (
      <Table.Row key={row._id}>
        <Table.Cell>{index}</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>{row.brandCode}</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>
          {row.colorName} ({row.colorCode}) - {row.collectionName} ({row.collectionCode})
        </Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>
          {row.skuSize} {row.skuType}
        </Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>{row.categoryCode}</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>{row.fabricType}</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>
          <Button color="red">Delete</Button>
        </Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
);
```

I keep getting below error in the console

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. See ... for more information.
    in ProductTableRows (at HomePage.js:64)
    in tbody (created by TableBody)
    in TableBody (at HomePage.js:63)
    in table (created by Table)
    in Table (at HomePage.js:51)
    in div (created by Segment)
    in Segment (at HomePage.js:50)
    in div (at HomePage.js:47)
    in HomePage (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:7)
    in div (at App.js:6)
    in App (at index.js:10)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at index.js:9)
```

What am I missing?

== update ==
I do see the _id value when I use the React Developer Tools in Chrome. See below picture [React Developer Tools Screenshot with key value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYLMG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the content of the table is still rendered you might have duplicated rows. Try logging the entire array or and see if that’s the case.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. I actually see the key/value in the React developer tools, but I don't see it in the rendered html.

Comment: The reason why you don’t see the duplicates is that react will only render one item per key. And there are multiple rows with the same key as the error describes. Try adding the index of the row just to make sure that all rows are rendered (remove when you’re done debugging) like this `key={\`${row._id}_${index}\`}`. It would be great to see the actual data passed to the table.

Comment: The key should be placed on the ProductTableSingleRow and not on the Table.Row inside of it.

Comment: Thanks @CarlRosell. The key was to pass the key to ProductTableSingleRow.